# Running War file with Jetty Runner in Heroku

Tags: heroku, jetty, war

If someone could give me some help on heroku I would appreciate.

If I run this command on my local console, it works on -> localhost:8080

> java -jar tools/jetty-runner-7.6.3.jar --port 8080 target/scala-2.9.1/myapp.war

---

So then I create the Procfile with this:

> web: java -jar tools/jetty-runner-7.6.3.jar --port 8080 target/scala-2.9.1/myapp.war

---

Then I test by running:

> foreman start

and it also works in -> localhost:8080

---

But after I deployed the app and make heroku open, it does not work...

> [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 22, 2012 11:16:59 AM
>
> -----> Discovering process types
>
> ```
>  Procfile declares types -> web
> ```
>
> -----> Compiled slug size is 70.0MB
>
> -----> Launching... done, v5
>
> ```
>   http://myapp.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
> ```
>
> To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
>
> XXXXX..XXXXX  master -> master

---

$heroku logs

> 2012-06-22T11:14:54+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
>
> 2012-06-22T11:17:57+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by my_email@my_email.com
>
> 2012-06-22T11:17:57+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy dcdd123 by my_email@my_email.com
>
> 2012-06-22T11:18:00+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
>
> 2012-06-22T11:18:21+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET myapp.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2012-06-22T11:18:30+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET myapp.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=

---

Any ideas, suggestions? Thanks,

Regards,
Andre

Comment: This comment should be converted to an answer and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Andre - We have a Heroku Labs feature that allows you to deploy WAR files directly to Heroku. Check out https://gist.github.com/a8c62301591a11b4c6e9 for exact details on how to go about doing it.

Comment: As of november 2014 this way of doing it is deprecated Take a look at this link for the correct way to do it now ; https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jetty runner to run your war you do not need to hard code the port number.
Heroku sets the port internally.

So your Procfile should be like:

`java -jar tools/jetty-runner-7.6.3.jar --port $PORT target/scala-2.9.1/myapp.war`